# Returning The Duplicate Column Values

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, duplicates

In the table below i have an id field name field and DateofBirth. The data type of dateofbirth is 'date'.

In the table, Alen's & Krizte's DateOfBirth are same (marked in Blue).

http://s24.postimg.org/j2wsw3r11/123.jpg
(Please dont edit this, i accidently put another table which has 2 similar dateofbirths too,i in another table lucky & stuart has same dob)

Now my question is this. I want to return the name of persons who have birthday on same day, like i said before. & iam using sql server 2008

I also want to know, if there are multiple instance like this in a table then how can we find that too ?? My english is not that great, if you have any questions then ask me, i will try to explain it more..!! Hope you understand what i just explained.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL2005+

```
SELECT src.*
FROM
(
    SELECT p.Id, 
        p.Name, 
        p.DateOfBirth, 
        COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY p.DateOfBirth) AS CountPerDateOfBirth
    FROM dbo.Person p
) src
WHERE src.CountPerDateOfBirth > 1
```

Note #1: I used COUNT function with [OVER clause](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) (requires SQL2005 min.).

Note #2: `PARTITION BY p.DateOfBirth` will split the source rows (dbo.MyTable) into many groups based on `DateOfBirth` values (17-07-1976, 13-01-1978, 26-04-1982, 26-04-1988):

```
-----------------------
1, Alen, 17-07-1976
4, Krizte, 17-07-1976
-----------------------
3, Sona, 13-01-1978
-----------------------
5, Lucky, 26-04-1982
-----------------------
2, Stuart, 26-04-1988
-----------------------
```

and *for every group* `COUNT(*)` will ... count the number of rows:

```
-----------------------
1, Alen, 17-07-1976,  2
4, Krizte, 17-07-1976,2
-----------------------
3, Sona, 13-01-1978  ,1
-----------------------
5, Lucky, 26-04-1982 ,1
-----------------------
2, Stuart, 26-04-1988,1
-----------------------
```

Comment: Can you please explain the concept used in this. iam a beginner, so it will be a lot helpful if you explained how it works step by step.